# Why do I need to run my sinatra app again when making changes and my environment is not :development?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, sass, compass-sass

I just implemented Compass configuration for my Sinatra app but when I change the environment to `:test` or `:production` and modify my files like `screen.sass` or `index.haml` my changes are not reflected when I reload the page so I need to run my app again?

Is it normal? Is is just me?

This is how my `app.rb` file looks like:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'sass'
require 'compass'
require './helpers.rb'

configure do
  set :environment, :test

  Compass.configuration do |config|
    settings.environment == :production ? 
      config.output_style = :compressed : 
      config.output_style = :nested
    settings.environment == :development ?
      config.line_comments = true :
      config.line_comments = false
  end

  set :sass, Compass.sass_engine_options
end

before do
  @js = 'javascript:;'
end

get '/scripts/jquery.js' do
  # Downloads the latest jQuery 1.x version when needed. Requires to reload the page after done.
  `curl "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" >> public/scripts/jquery.js`
end

get '/styles/:name.css' do
  sass :"styles/#{params[:name]}"
end

get '/?' do
  haml :index
end

get '/:page/?' do
  haml params[:page].to_sym
end
```

---

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if you make a change to a running Sinatra application, you have to restart the application, as the program has already been loaded to memory.

There are options for automatically detecting changes and restarting the application on the [Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading).

Comment: But I was talking about my site files, such as `index.haml` or `screen.sass`. As far as I know, I don't need to re-run the app in order to see changes over that files. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: By the way. Shotgun solves this partially, since it is not necessary to re-run the app for each change over site files.

Comment: Does the application display different `haml` or `sass` files depending on the environment loaded?

Comment: No, the same files. Except that Sass has different configuration depending on the environment, just that.

Comment: AFAIK, you do need to restart your app for the changes on HAML and SASS to update the generated (compiled) files. At least I think I can vouch that for HAML (on Rails apps), where I restart the app through passenger.

Comment: Since Shotgun fix the issue partially (reloading the files for your at production, maybe try with Sinatra::Reloader which, IMHO, works better than Shotgun. 

Maybe something like

    require "sinatra"

    configure(:production) do |c|
      require "sinatra/reloader"
      c.also_reload "*.sass"
    end

That being said, are you sure you do need this kind of behavior on a production/test environment for updating? Development env. should be (at least, for what I use it for) for this kind of hot testing.

Answer (score 0):

Since Shotgun fix the issue partially (reloading the files for your at production, maybe try with Sinatra::Reloader which, IMHO, works better than Shotgun.

Maybe something like (not tested)

```
require "sinatra"

configure(:production) do |c|
  require "sinatra/reloader"
  c.also_reload "*.sass", "*.haml"
end
```

That being said, are you sure you do need this kind of behavior on a production/test environment for updating? Development env. should be (at least, for what I use it for) for this kind of hot testing.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use sinatra::reloader
but I didn't like the huge dependencies incurred (as should we all be mindful how many gems get activated)

pistol ( at a tender age of ver 0.0.2) and I think does the required job nicely

Answer (score 0):

I use shotgum gem for this.

```
gem install shotgun
```

then

```
shotgun app.rb
```

from within the app dir

this then reloads the app per request, rather than holding the whole thing in memory.  you access the site on localhost:9393